# dplyr approach for sumifs like excel

Tags: r, dplyr

i have a key in tableA and in tableB i have key and numeric. How can i achieve formula excel sumifs(numeric,tableB.key,tableA.key,tableA.key,1)
with dplyr without join the two table

i already tried summarise_if within mutate

```
mutate(newColumn = summarise_if(tableB, .predicate = tableB$Key == .$Key, .funs = sum(tableB$numeric)))

but i get this error

In tableB$Key == .$Key:
 longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

```
tableA         tableB
key             key numeric 
1               1   10
2               1   30
3
4



Expected
key  newColumn
1    40
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try

```
library(tidyverse)

tableA <- tibble(key = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
tableB <- tibble(key = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
                 numeric = c(10, 30, 10, 15))

(function(){

  tmpDF <- tableB %>%
    filter(key %in% tableA$key) %>%
    group_by(key) %>%
    summarise(newColumn = sum(numeric))

  tableA %>%
    mutate(new = ifelse(key == tmpDF$key, tmpDF$newColumn, 0)
    )

})()
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#    key   new
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#     1    40
#     2    25
#     3     0
#     4     0
```

Comment: this is  good solution, but with this solution if I want newColumn in tableA I have to explicitly join the tableA with tableB. 
Is there another way that you can %>% the tableA directly by mutate or summarise_if or others without join them explicitly(left_join())?

Comment: I have adapted my suggestion, should work now in the way you wanted